# How do I stop multiple custom Gutenberg blocks from duplicating fields in the inspector controls?

Tags: wordpress, jsx, gutenberg-blocks

So I wrote a custom block that allows the user to assign either a left or right float to an image when they add an inline image using the rich text editor.

[image]

The block works as intended and the inspector control correctly floats the image; however, when I add a second instance of the block, both blocks get changed when I changed the select field in the inspector controls. I assume this is because both instance of the block use the same function and variables, but I am not sure how to resolve the issue.

Here is a snippet from the edit function that my custom block uses:

```
 edit: ( { attributes, setAttributes } ) => {

        const onChangeContent = ( newContent ) => {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        };

    function onChangefloat( newfloat ) {
        setAttributes( { float: newfloat } );
    }

        return (
            <div { ...useBlockProps() }>

                <InspectorControls key="setting">
                    <div id="placeholder-id-name" class="p-3">
                        <SelectControl
                            label="Image Float Direction"
                            value={ attributes.float }
                            options={ [
                                { value: 'left', label: 'Left' },
                                { value: 'right', label: 'Right' },
                            ] }
                            onChange={ onChangefloat }
                        />
                    </div>
                </InspectorControls> 

                <RichText
                    tagName="p"
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                    value={ attributes.content }
                    placeholder={ __( 'Content...' ) }
                />

            </div>
        );
    },
```

Thank you in advance! :)

I tried to alter the function but I am a bit lost on what I can even do or if a new approach is needed. I thought perhaps finding a way to assign unique ids to each instance of the block might help but I could not find an effective way to do that.